# Access static variable in non-static method + Inheritance

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, static, non-static

I have the following stucture

```
class Foo
{
    public static $a = "parent";

    public static function Load()
    {
        return static::$a;
    }

    public function Update()
    {
        return self::$a; 
    }

}

class Bar extends Foo
{
    private static $a = "child";
}
```

I want the Update function to be able to return $a aswell, but I can't get it to work.

```
Bar::Load();  //returns child, Correct.
$bar = new Bar();
$bar->Update(); //returns parent, Wrong.
```

I've tried self:: , static:: and get_class() without success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `self::$a` in `update()`

```
class Foo
{
    protected static $a = "parent"; // Notice this is now "protected"

    public function child()
    {
        return static::$a; 
    }

    public function parent()
    {
        return self::$a; 
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo
{
    protected static $a = "child"; // Notice this is now "protected"
}

$bar = new Bar();
print $bar->child() . "\n";
print $bar->parent() . "\n";
```

Comment: Isn't the real error that `$a` is being declared as private when it's public in the parent class?

Comment: @tigrang, I wondered about that also, but if they aren't getting any errors then it would only be a recommended/strict change and shouldn't effect the actual execution.

Comment: I'm trying with php 5.4 and 5.3.10 and getting a fatal error because of it. http://codepad.viper-7.com/2THHHk

Answer (score 1):

See my code

```
class Foo
{
    protected static $a = "parent";

    public static function Load()
    {
        return static::$a;
    }

    public function Update()
    {
        return static::$a; 
    }

}

class Bar extends Foo
{
    protected static $a = "child";
}
Bar::Load();  //returns child, Correct.
$bar = new Bar();
$bar->Update(); //returns child, Correct.
```